# Sailsjs: How to populate association after *update* to model?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, waterline

I have the following controller code that works for **index**, **show**, **create** methods but the update fails when I include populate - what am I doing wrong?

```
  // User List
  index: function(req, res) {
    User.find()
    .populate('profile')
    .exec(function(err, users) {
      if (err) return res.json(err, 400);
      if (!users) return res.json(users, 404);
      res.json(users, 200);
    });
  },

  // Single User
  show: function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({ username: req.param('username') })
    .populate('profile')
    .exec(function(err, user) {
      if (err) return res.json(err, 400);
      if (!user) return res.json(user, 404);
      res.json(user, 200);
    });
  },

  // Create User
  create: function(req, res) {
    User.create(req.body, function(err, user) {
      if (err) return res.json(err, 400);
      Person.create({user: user.id, slug: user.username}, function(err, profile) {
        if (err) return res.json(err, 400);
        User.update(user.id, {profile: profile.id})
        .populate('profile')
        .exec(function(err, user) {
          if (err) return res.json(err, 400);
        });
        user.profile = profile;
        res.json(user, 200);
      });
    });
  },

  // Update User
  update: function(req, res) {
    var username = req.param('username');
    User.update({ username: username }, req.body)
    .populate('profile')
    .exec(function(err, user) {
      if (err) return res.json(err, 400);
      res.json(user, 201);
    });
  },
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `.populate('profile')`? Apologies, I'm a Sails/Waterline newbie -- is it always necessary to call `.populate()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models) the `update` function takes a callback to which it passes the updated records.
Example from the doc :

```
// For example, to update a user's name,
// .update(query, params to change, callback)
User.update({
  name: 'sally'
},{
  phone: '555-555-5555'
}, function(err, users) {
  // Error handling
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  // Updated users successfully!
  } else {
    console.log("Users updated:", users);
  }
});
```

Applied to your code, it would look like this :

```
// Update User
update: function(req, res) {
  var username = req.param('username');
  User.update({ username: username }, req.body)
  .exec(function(err, users) {
    if (err) {
      return res.json(err, 400);
    }

    var user = users.slice(0,1); // Take the first user in the array
    User.findOne(user.id) // You may try something like User._model(user) instead to avoid another roundtrip to the DB.
    .populate('profile')
    .exec(function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json(err, 400);
      }
      res.json(user, 201);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: code doesn't work... see my answer below... adjust and i'll give you the cred

Answer (score 4):

Jeremie your answer is correct in essence but has a few issues:

- the user object returned by the update call and then sliced does not
  have a `populate` function
- slice the `users` list returns a list instead of the object desired

Personal preference but I also prefer the following which uses the `exec` call instead of the callback.

```
  update: function(req, res) {
    var id = req.param('id');
    User
    .update(id, req.params.all())
    .exec(function(err, users) {
      if(err) return res.json(err, 400);
      var user = users[0];
      console.log('ID', user.id);
      User
      .findOne(user.id)
      .populate('profile')
      .exec(function (err, user){
        if (err) return res.json(err, 400);
        res.json(user, 201);
      });
    });
  },
```